# SQL create enum as column and group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below

| id | folder_num | category | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100/2021 | add | 8/25/2021 20:58 |
| 2 | 200/2021 | delete | 8/25/2021 21:02 |
| 3 | 300/2021 | add | 8/25/2021 21:06 |
| 4 | 400/2021 | add | 8/25/2021 21:10 |
| 5 | 500/2021 | delete | 8/26/2021 21:14 |
| 6 | 600/2021 | edit | 8/26/2021 21:18 |
| 7 | 700/2021 | edit | 8/27/2021 21:22 |
| 8 | 800/2021 | edit | 8/27/2021 21:26 |
| 9 | 900/2021 | edit | 8/27/2021 21:30 |
| 10 | 1000/2021 | add | 8/27/2021 21:34 |

column `category` is a column with type enum, I want to make the contents of the enum into a column and group it by date.

I have previously created a grouping based on `category` and `date` with the following results.

```
SELECT c.category, 
        COUNT(l.id) total,  
        d.date as date
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM log) c
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) date FROM log WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2021-08-01' AND '2021-08-30') d
 LEFT JOIN log l ON l.category = c.category AND DATE(l.date) = d.date
 GROUP BY c.category, d.date
 ORDER BY c.category ASC
```

| category | total | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| add | 3 | 8/25/2021 |
| delete | 1 | 8/25/2021 |
| edit | 0 | 8/25/2021 |
| add | 0 | 8/26/2021 |
| delete | 1 | 8/26/2021 |
| edit | 1 | 8/26/2021 |
| add | 1 | 8/27/2021 |
| delete | 0 | 8/27/2021 |
| edit | 3 | 8/27/2021 |

the result is quite satisfactory, but back to my question, I want to make the value in the `category` column into a column instead of a row, something like this the result

| date | add | delete | edit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/25/2021 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 8/26/2021 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 8/27/2021 | 1 | 0 | 3 |

I tried to use the max(case ...) function but the code is error, here's what I tried

```
SELECT 
        d.date as date,
        max(case when d.category = 'add' then COUNT(l.id) else null end) as add,
        max(case when d.category = 'delete' then COUNT(l.id) else null end) as delete,
        max(case when d.category = 'edit' then COUNT(l.id) else null end) as edit
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM log) c
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) date FROM log WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2021-08-01' AND '2021-08-30') d
 LEFT JOIN log l ON l.category = c.category AND DATE(l.date) = d.date
 GROUP BY d.date
```

is the use of the function in my query misplaced? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest aggregation functions, but you can simply use:

```
SELECT date(l.date) as date,
       sum(l.category = 'add') as add,
       sum(l.category = 'delete') as delete,
       sum(l.category = 'edit') as edit
FROM log l
WHERE l.date >= '2021-08-01' AND l.date < '2021-08-31'
GROUP BY l.date
```